# I want to know list parmeters in python function like a[:]

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
pset = []
def powe(a):
     powehelp(a,0)
def powehelp(a, ind):
    if len(a) == ind:
        pset.append(a)
        return
    powehelp(a[:], ind+1)
    a.pop(ind)
    powehelp(a[:],ind)


powe([1,2,3])
print(pset)
```

This code creates its subset, and in this code I want to know why I can't use `powehelp(a, ind+1)` instead of `powehelp(a[:], ind+1)`?

I know that `a[:]` means get all the values ​​of list `a`.

When using `a`, the result is `[[], [], [], []]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `powehelp` function uses `pop`, which means it alters the list it is given.

If you pass `a` into it, it is `a` that gets altered, and evidently ends up empty.

`a[:]` creates a copy of `a`. If you pass `a[:]` into `powehelp`, your original list `a` is unaffected.

Comment: oh i can understand, thanks for your fast, exact answer

Answer (score 0):

The given `a` is a list in itself, and so appending a list to a list would make a nested list.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = []
b.append(a)
b
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

When you `pset.append(a)` you insert the list `a` into the endtail of the list `pset` so you result is a nested list. If I understand your requirement correctly, you're looking to concatenate your lists, as in:

```
c = [4, 5, 6]
a + c
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```